# Rails API wrap_parameters only for create and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I have Rails API app with JSON output and below wrap_parameters settings

```
/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb

# Enable parameter wrapping for JSON.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  include ActionController::ParamsWrapper
  wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
end
```

This is fine but problem is now that it wraps for index, show and destroy aswell and I'm getting errors where it adds params with model name which causes errors `parameter is required`

Is there a way to avoid this for certain set of actions?